# Сбор HTML с сайтов. Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, http, python-2.x

Встал вопрос: Есть ли какой-нибудь способ собрать HTML код с интересующего меня сайта и как-то  вывести это на экран или записать в файл? (Python)
Т.е.например, я ввожу Apple.com, и мне выдает его HTML разметку.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ пробовали?

Comment: Да. Куча библиотек для работы c HTTP на ваш выбор https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с сетью есть удобная библиотека [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
# pip install requests
import requests

rs = requests.get('https://www.apple.com/')
print(rs)  # <Response [200]>
print(rs.content)  # Страница HTML в байтах
print(rs.text)  # Страница HTML в строке

# Сохранение в файл
with open('apple.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(rs.content)
```